# Location Services enabled for specific app?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is there any way to determine whether location services have been disabled for a specific app? The problem is that [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] returns YES even if location services have been disabled for a specific app...

Answer (score 10):

If you're targeting iOS 4.2 and above, just use `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]`

It will return one of the following `CLAuthorizationStatus` values which are basically just integers:

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

Search the docs for "CLLocationManager" for more info.

Answer (score 5):

When you implement the delegate for location manager, you should be implementing didFailWithError. In there you will get the appropriate error if the user did not allow access to location

**[Apple Documentation States:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html)**
If the user denies your application’s use of the location service, this method reports a `kCLErrorDenied` error. Upon receiving such an error, you should stop the location service.

Comment: Is there any other way? ís The function similar function: locationServicesEnabled?. In your case, your way is also a bit complicated.

Comment: @becktoan it is what it is, read the documentation link I provided above